# Inserting multiple values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I added a new column to an existing table(columns acadid,orgid,childid) and now I want to insert values for it.

```
alter table table1 add new_parent int

insert into table (new_parent) select parent from (select parent
from table2 o inner join table1 ou
on ou.orgid=o.orgunitid)  np
```

Here:

```
 select parent
  from table2 o inner join table1 ou
  on ou.orgid=o.orgunitid
```

this query gives me multiple values(multiple rows) for the new parent column.

But the above code gives me the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'acadid', table
>   'tempdb.dbo.table1_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_000000014F2B'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been
>   terminated.

How can I fix it?

Comment: seems like your table has a column 'acadid' with not null constraint, and you are trying to insert a new row with value for only one column (new_parent)

Comment: The error message is obvious ! Put the error message in google.

Comment: first in your code you alter `TABLE1` but after than you try to insert record into table called `table` which is not valid SQL Server tablename, not into `TABLE1`. And which DBMS is this? you listed [tag:MySQL] and [tag:SQL-SERVER]

Comment: I dont want to add new rows I want to add values of new_parent in the already existing rows. How can I do that?

Comment: @user3325454: Try with `update table1 set new_parent=(select ...) where orgid=...` or the same with `where orgid in (...)`.

Comment: @Ravinder: I tried that but it gives the following error:
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: use `in` if subquery returned multiple rows. `where orgid in (...)`

Comment: @Ravinder: didn't work. Anything else that you can suggest?
acadid  oldpt  orgid    new_parent
226 488 963 NULL
226 488 965 NULL
226 488 967 NULL
226 488 963 NULL
226 488 963 NULL
226 488 964 NULL
226 488 965 NULL

I am trying to add value for new_parent for all the rows using single query.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have this error message is that you added a new column to your **table1** table with the **alter table** statement, but instead of updating the value of this column for existing rows, you are adding new rows with only this column filled with an **insert** statement, and there may be a constraint (a primary key constraint?) on another column that does not allow nulls.

Instead of that, you probably want to update the value of this new column for the existing rows with an **update** like:

```
update table1
set table1.new_parent = table2.parent
from table1 inner join table2 on table2.orgid=table1.orgunitid
```